# Lightning:input one message for field missing and another when name is taken

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning:input field for a name and I need it to show one message when it's left empty and another when the name entered is already taken. Part of the problem is that I can only check for the duplicate name once save is pressed. At the moment I've tried  to have both messageWhenValueMissing and messageWhenBadInput on the input but then it displays the default 'complete this field' instead of my message and does nothing when the name is taken.

Please give me an example of how I could do this so I can apply it to my code, thanks

Comment: Welcome to the forum.. Please, can you add your code so we can see what have you done so far? It will be much faster if can see the code you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that v.validity became strictly readonly in summer '18 so when I was setting badInput:true it did nothing, had to use setCustomValidity instead and now it all works.